# Django: Sorting by many to one fields that might be missing in some rows

Tags: django

I have something similar to the following example - I've rewritten it below to simplify it.

Each `Measurement` can have an arbitrary number of `Samples` (but only one of each `SampleDefiniton`).  Not every `Sample` is required - some are missing.  I want to sort my `Measurements` by a specific `SampleDefinition`, but I don't want to exclude the `Measurements` that are missing the specific `Sample`.

```
class Measurement(model):
    timestamp = DateTimeField()

class SampleDefinition(model):
    name = CharString()

class Sample(model):
    value = IntegerField()
    measurement = ForeignKey(Measurement)
    definition = ForeignKey(SampleDefinition)
```

Here is how I do it now, first by *filtering* for the definition we're sorting by, and the sorting by it:

```
measurements = Measurement.objects.\
    filter(sample__definition=id_to_sort_by).\
    order_by('sample__value', 'timestamp')
```

Then, grabbing the rest...

```
others = Measurement.objects.\
         exclude(id__in=list([s.id for s in
                              measurements]).\
         order_by('timestamp')
```

And finally combining using `lists` to preserve the sort:

```
final = list(measurements) + list(others)
```

It seems like this could be done in a single query in Django and I suspect I could do it using Django's `When` by interpreting the missing sample as `NULL`.  The problem is the underlying join will still give me multiple rows per `Measurement`.

Here's an attempt that I think is close but returns duplicate rows:

```
Measurement.objects.\
annotate(sort_field=Case(When(sample__definition=13,
                              then=F('sample__value')),
                              default=Value(None), 
                              output_field=IntegerField())).\
distinct().\
order_by(F('sort_field').asc(nulls_last=True), 'timestamp')
```

Is this possible to do in native Django?

Edit: I also tried `measurments.union(others)`, but this gives me an issue with `others` not being a join -- so causes Django issues if, for example, I take the resulting query and do `.values()` against it and ask for `sample__`value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out -- the `annotate` is what makes the `union` difficult.  But it's not needed!

```
haves = Measurement.objects.\
   filter(sample__definition=definition).\
   order_by('sample__value', 'timestamp')

have_nots = Measurement.objects.\
   exclude(id__in=haves).\
   order_by('timestamp')

everything = haves.union(have_nots, all=True)  # Use all=True to preserve sort.
```

So the first query sorts and filters by the rows that actually have the `Sample` we want.  We then `union` (append) the rest of the `Measurements` missing the specific `Sample`.

Where this got difficult in previous attempts was doing an annotation and then sorting by the annotation.  Getting rid of the annotation keeps the two queries identical so that they can easily be `union`'ed.

In my real world problem I use the `annotate` to apply an SQL function -- but I've since realized that function can be applied directly in the `order_by`, preventing the extra columns which make the `union` difficult:

```
Blah.objects.order_by(Func('field'))
```

Answer (score 1):

**Possible Solution with 3 queries**

```
qs1 = Measurement.objects.filter(sample__defintion=13).annotate(sort_field=F("sample__value").order_by("sort_field", "timestamp")
qs2 = Measurement.objects.exclude(id__in=qs1).order_by("timestamp")
qs = list(qs1) + list(qs2)
```

**Another Solution with 2 queries**

```
Measurement.objects.annotate(
    upper=Subquery(Sample.objects.filter(measurement=OuterRef("id"), defintion_id=13)).order_by("value").values("value")[:1]
).order_by(F('upper').desc(nulls_last=True))
```

The thing is, the last solution with When should work properly if you remove the .distinct() and change the default to 0 rather than None. Let me know the results!

EDIT: If I'm not mistaken, there are multiple entries for a single measurement in the sample table where the sample definition is different. So it's expected for the Case/When query to have duplicate rows returned. You could rectify this by doing this.

```
m = Measurement.objects.annotate(
    sort_field=Case(When(sample__definition=13, then=F('sample__value')), default=Value(None), output_field=IntegerField())
)
m = m.order_by(F('sort_field').asc(nulls_last=True)).values("id").distinct()
```

Comment: If the amswer was correct please select it as the correct answer :)

Comment: Looking at this again.  I actually tried qs1.union(qs2) ... and then found I get django errors occasionally because qs1 is not quite the same as qs2 in that qs1 is a join -- so if I reference sample__value, I get errors because qs2 can't pull in that value.